# Populate DataGridViewComboBoxCell from DataTable not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I'm trying to populate a datagridview with comboboxes in ***specific cells***.

```
// Create data table based on source data
DataTable dt_SourceMapping = new DataTable("SourceMapping"); // This is the main datatable to bind to the data grid view

// Set Columns (clone)    
dt_SourceMapping = dt.Clone(); // I already have 'dt' defined elsewhere as a datatable and it is already loaded with data. 
                   // I use this method to get the same columns for dt_SourceMapping
// Clear rows
dt_SourceMapping.Clear(); // I clear the existing rows because I want to add the below rows
dt_SourceMapping.Rows.Add(); // Ignore/Map
dt_SourceMapping.Rows.Add(); // Target col
dt_SourceMapping.Rows.Add(); // Source data type
dt_SourceMapping.Rows.Add(); // Target data type
dt_SourceMapping.Rows.Add(); // Data formatting


// Ignore/Map
// Here I am creating a datatable to store the values for Ignore/Map (ie, 2 options)
DataTable dt_Map_IgnoreMap = new DataTable("MapCBOptions");
dt_Map_IgnoreMap.Columns.Add("IgnoreMap");
dt_Map_IgnoreMap.Rows.Add("Ignore");
dt_Map_IgnoreMap.Rows.Add("Map");

// Here I am defining a new DGVComboBoxCell and binding it to the datatable
DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgvcb_IgnoreMap = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
dgvcb_IgnoreMap.DataSource = dt_Map_IgnoreMap;
dgvcb_IgnoreMap.DisplayMember = "IgnoreMap";
dgvcb_IgnoreMap.ValueMember = "IgnoreMap";


// Set datagridview mapping source
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt_SourceMapping;

// Assign the combox to Column 1, row 0 (just for testing)
dataGridView1[1,0] = dgvcb_IgnoreMap;
```

But the result in the datagrid view shows as blank (no items listed in the combo box):
[image: DGV Result]

dt_Map_IgnoreMap does register the Rows.

But this is what I see for dgvcb_IgnoreMap:
[image: dgvcb_IgnoreMap]

I do think this is where the issue is, but I don't understand what is wrong with it. I've populated other comboxes (not DataGridViews) similarly from a DataSet, and they work fine.

I have tried looking at these on SO already (as well as spending a few hours searching the internet) but my last resort is coming here as I'm stumped!

[DataGridViewComboBoxCell populated but will not display content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56941772/datagridviewcomboboxcell-populated-but-will-not-display-content)

[How to populate each DataGridViewComboBoxCell with different data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446600/how-to-populate-each-datagridviewcomboboxcell-with-different-data)

[DataGridViewComboBoxCell valueValue is invalid with binded DataGridViewComboBoxCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854881/datagridviewcomboboxcell-valuevalue-is-invalid-with-binded-datagridviewcomboboxc)

**UPDATE:**

I am finally able to re-visit this project and hoping to pick up where I left off. I'm still having issues with this piece.

Here is a screenshot of how I want it to look like (in excel):
[image: Excel example]

**UPDATE 2:**

I think it is an issue to do with the data source being bound.

As a test, I just created 5 blank rows and 3 columns:

```
// ADD columns and rows
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
dataGridView1.RowCount = 5;
```

And I used the same code for assigned the datagridview combo boxcell, and it worked:

[image]

So I guess my question now is, how can I edit a DGV that is using a bound source?

I tried these:

```
// format data grid view
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = true;
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;            
dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystrokeOrF2;
```

but they still don't work.

Comment: I've updated the post. I think the issue is to do with using a bound data source. Ie, I can't seem to update datagridview cells that are using a bound data source. Hoping someone can assist with overcoming this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was due to the data grid view being bound to the data table being (I did this to get the column headers initially).

In case anyone else searching this in the future wants an possible solution, this is what I did (only showing one combobox as an example):

```
// Create data table based on source data
DataTable dt_SourceMapping = new DataTable("SourceMapping"); // This is the main datatable to bind to the data grid view

// Set Columns (clone)    
dt_SourceMapping = dt.Clone(); // I already have 'dt' defined elsewhere as a datatable and it is already loaded with data. 
// I use this method to get the same columns for dt_SourceMapping
// Clear rows
dt_SourceMapping.Clear(); // I clear the existing rows because I want to add the below rows
dt_SourceMapping.Rows.Add(); // Ignore/Map
dt_SourceMapping.Rows.Add(); // Target col
dt_SourceMapping.Rows.Add(); // Source data type
dt_SourceMapping.Rows.Add(); // Target data type
dt_SourceMapping.Rows.Add(); // Data formatting

// Add Columns to DGV and remove sortable
foreach (DataColumn column in dt_SourceMapping.Columns)
{               
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
    dataGridView1.Columns[column.Ordinal].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}

// Add dummy rows
dataGridView1.RowCount = 6;

// format data grid view
dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 5;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystrokeOrF2;

// ADD combobox
//------------------------------------------------
// Row 0: IgnoreMap
// Ignore/Map
DataTable dt_Map_IgnoreMap = new DataTable("MapCBOptions");
dt_Map_IgnoreMap.Columns.Add("IgnoreMap");
dt_Map_IgnoreMap.Rows.Add("Ignore");
dt_Map_IgnoreMap.Rows.Add("Map");
//------------------------------------------------

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    // Row 0: IgnoreMap
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgvcb_IgnoreMap = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell
    {
        DataSource = dt_Map_IgnoreMap,
        DisplayMember = "IgnoreMap",
        ValueMember = "IgnoreMap"
    };
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[i] = dgvcb_IgnoreMap;
}
```

End result:

[image: Result]